# How to place links (or alternative) in TextView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview

In Android Studio how to make something like links in one TextView, or maybe place two TextViews as a whole line. Something like:

John Appleseed likes your answer.

And when user taps on John Appleseed a new activity with user's profile starts.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to do something similar before, where some links in the TextView did open the browser, and one opened a specific fragment in the app itself.

I made a gist of it, since it is quite long.

Please note that it is a bit old code, but it should be fine: https://gist.github.com/dzolnai/b109f9abb9bf6bd1b363cfc52a00871d

You would be interested in the URL `app://schedule`. Of course you can use something different, as long as you handle the click yourself.